# Listview not displaying data but showing namespace plus datamodel

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8.1

I am using the folloowing class but its not allowing me to display show_times in my xaml its just comming up

popcornpk.datamodel.fetchtiming

```
 public class FetchTiming
 {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string theater_name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public List<string> show_times { get; set; }
        public string screen_id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
}

public class MovieDetail
{
        public MovieDetails movie_details { get; set; }
        public List<FetchTiming> fetch_timing { get; set; }
}
```

My Class call

```
public async Task<MovieDetail> GetMovieShowtimesAsync()
{
        string jsonresult = await WCFRESTServiceCall("GET", "movie_details");
        var jarray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MovieDetail>(jsonresult);


        return jarray;
```

}

This is my xamlmethod call I hav eno idea what is going on the data is being returned ok but I just cant seem to dispaly it

```
private async void listViewShowtimes_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        popcornpk_Dal _dal = new popcornpk_Dal();
        MovieDetail _showTimes = await _dal.GetMovieShowtimesAsync();

        var listView = (ListView)sender;

        listView.ItemsSource = _showTimes.fetch_timing.ToList();
```

}

Xaml Of DataTemplate

```
<PivotItem x:Name="pvtShowTimes" Header="showtimes">
<Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ListView x:Name="listViewShowtimes" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Loaded="listViewShowtimes_Loaded">
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Height="505">

                            <TextBlock FontSize="13" x:Name="txtshowtime"  Text="{Binding theater_name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,223,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212" Foreground="White" Height="29" SelectionChanged="txtTtile_SelectionChanged"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="13" x:Name="txtshow_times"  Text="{Binding address}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,223,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212" Foreground="White" Height="29" SelectionChanged="txtTtile_SelectionChanged"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView>
</Grid>                
</PivotItem>
```

Below is a screen shot of the app running on the device any help be greatly apreciated.
[image]

Ok So i have it at least displaying the thertre name which is good on the show times screen but its still not allowing me to display the show_times field.

```
 <ListView x:Name="listViewShowtimes" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Loaded="listViewShowtimes_Loaded">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>

  <DataTemplate>

                        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition  />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock FontSize="13"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="txtshowtime"  Text="{Binding theater_name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212" Foreground="White" Height="29" />
                                <TextBlock FontSize="13" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="txtshow_times"  Text="{Binding show_times}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212" Foreground="White" Height="29" />


                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

I think what i need to no is how to bind a list of strings through xaml Problem I have i need the show times to appear below the cinema name you see their 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have Text="{Binding show_times}"  so In your class FetchTiming,

```
public List<string> show_times { get; set; }
```

is a list so if you bind it to a TextBlock, it will simply do ToString(). You have to add inside the template another ListView like:

```
 <TextBlock FontSize="13"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="txtshowtime"  Text="{Binding theater_name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212" Foreground="White" Height="29" />
 <ListView ItemsSource={Binding show_times} />
```

And will do the trick.